# Вызов не-управляемой dll с открытием окна из управляемого кода - нужны идеи

Tags: c#

Из управляемого кода (написанного на C#) я работаю с обычной(не-управляемой) dll.
Эта dll-ка не моя, исходников нет.

В этой dll много функций - они все отрабатываю правильно кроме одной - функция без параметров, при вызове должна открыть окошко для ввода информации о лицензии.

При вызове этой функции окошко открывается "не дорисованной" и все зависает (выхода из этой функции нет).

Если я вызываю эту-же функцию из кода на с++ - все Ок.
Повторю - параметров у этой функции нет ни каких.

Нужны идеи: из за чего это может происходить?

Comment: Конкретнее. Какой тип проекта, приведите примеры, как вызываете функцию на С++ и на C#

Comment: Включите в стадии отладку чужого нативного кода и попробуйте достать стек вызовов при зависании.